# Gem's configuration not being set in Rails initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am making a ruby gem let's call it **Radin**. It is used in Rails projects. There is an installation process that creates `config/initializers/radin.rb` by running `rails generate radin:install`.

*config/initializers/radin.rb* (Rails project)

```
Radin.configure do |config|
  # Set this options to what makes sense for you
  config.option = 'test'
end
```

The generator works as intended (as seen above). In my gem I am following two links [MyGem.configure Block](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/mygem-configure-block) and [Config and Generators in Gems](https://rarlindseysmash.com/posts/config-and-generators-in-gems).

I have a executable to check if the configurations have been set.

*/exe/radin*

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'radin'
output = {}
output["option"] = Radin::Documentor.test_configuration

puts "Output: #{output}"
```

My Documentor class only outputs my one configuration option

*/lib/radin/documentor.rb*

```
module Radin
  class Documentor
    def self.test_configuration
      Radin.configuration.option
    end
  end
end
```

Finally I have my `Radin` module and `Configuration` class

*/lib/radin.rb*

```
require "radin/version"
require 'json'

module Radin

  autoload :Documentor, 'radin/documentor'

  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configure
    self.configuration ||= Configuration.new
    yield(configuration)
  end

  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :option

    def initialize
      @option = 'default_option'
    end
  end
end
```

When I run `$ radin` in a test rails application directory I get an error, despite having the configuration option set in `config/initializers/radin.rb`.

> .../radin/lib/radin/documentor.rb:8:in `test_configuration': undefined
>   method`option' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

**Tried & Failed**
I've tried to set change the module to always have a default set, but despite changing the configuration in the initializer the option never changes from 'default_option'.

```
module Radin

  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configuration
    @configuration ||= Configuration.new
  end

  def self.configure
    yield(configuration)
  end

  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my executable file `radin` I added:

```
begin
  load File.join(Dir.pwd, 'config', 'initializers', 'radin.rb')
rescue LoadError
  puts "Please run `rails generate radin:install` before continuing "
end
```

and everything seems to work correctly now.